# What are the protocols of flying over conflict areas?

Tags: safety, flight-planning

Apparently [Malaysia Airlines Flight 17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH17) used a general airway over the east of Ukraine, which currently is ['in conflict'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_pro-Russian_unrest_in_Ukraine).

What are the 'normal' procedures regarding (not) flying over conflict areas? Who is responsible for an up-to-date risk assessment? Who advises? Who makes the (final) decision?

Comment: Here's an op-ed in the New York Times you might be interested in: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/07/19/opinion/malaysia-airlines-flight-17-the-ukraine-wars-victim.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=c-column-top-span-region&region=c-column-top-span-region&WT.nav=c-column-top-span-region&_r=0

Comment: BBC: [Who, what, why: How often do planes fly over conflict zones?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-28364306)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is horrendous Incident, and my heart goes out to the victims Families who lost their loved ones.**

---

The FAA filed a special Warning flying over Crimea back in April but apparently not where the airplane went down.

The procedure is to avoid flying over (Dead/No fly Zones) which Aviation Authorities are responsible in providing to the Airline companies so they can adjust their flight plans.

FAA Warning over flying over Crimea.

[image]

[image]

Planes Flight Path.

[image]

Comment: Did the EASA publish a NOTAM for the area as well?

Comment: Yes, on the same date (3rd of April) --- http://www.aviationnews-online.com/regulatory/easa-issues-crimea-safety-warning/

Comment: Note that the above FDC NOTAM concerns the Crimean peninsula and surrounding airspace, and does not cover the region of current conflicts in eastern Ukraine.

Comment: @casey -- The Route was closed @ FL320 but the plane was @ FL330 -- by the looks of it there was plenty of traffic on that route -- http://www.wired.com/2014/07/the-crashed-malaysia-airlines-plane-wasnt-the-only-jet-in-ukraine-airspace/

Comment: @casey Sure but the question is about normal procedures for (not) flying over conflict areas. The NOTAM quoted is an example of such normal procedures.